# Is the expression "If [commands -gt value]" acceptable?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, scripting

I want to make a loop command which will disable my CPU if it's running at low usage. First I tried to make a simple command like this:

```
A=[ $top -bn1 | grep CPU |head -1 |sed s/"%"/""/g|awk '{print $8}' ]

B="2"

if [ $A -gt $B ]
then
    echo a
else
    echo b
fi
```

But it says "Not Found and Unexpected"

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend.

Comment: `A=[ foo ]` runs `foo ]` as a command, with an environment variable `A` set to the value `[`. Surely that's not what you actually intend to do.

Comment: ...it might be helpful to realize that `[` is not actually grouping syntax in shell. Rather, it's shorthand for `test`: `[ foo ]` is the same as `test foo` (historically, using `/usr/bin/[` as a hardlink to the implementation at `/usr/bin/test`). So, if you wouldn't write `A=test $top -bn1`, you can't reasonably write `A=[ $top -bn1 ]`.

Comment: i dont realy understand what u called hardlink xD, seems like it's already corrected by ruakh, but thanks. Anyway my linux likely doesnt provide "foo" command, just and very old modem..

Comment: `foo` is a metasyntactic variable -- that is, it's a stand in for other commands; when I say "foo", that could be `top` or `grep` or any other thing. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable

Comment: Does the answer I wrote below is working for you ? Please comment the answer if you still have issues

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
A=[ $top -bn1 | grep CPU |head -1 |sed s/"%"/""/g|awk '{print $8}' ]
```

does not make any sense at all. I'm guessing you meant to write:

```
A="$(top -bn1 | grep CPU | head -1 | sed s/%//g | awk '{print $8}')"
```

---

**Edited to add:** After running the above, you should check that `"$A"` expands to what you think it does. (Note, in particular, that it has to be an integer, since shell arithmetic only supports integers.)

Comment: ./g.sh[9]: 92.0: unexpected '.'
Anyway tnx, likely its doesnt accept comma style

Comment: Huh? "Comma style?"

Answer (score 0):

If you want `A` to be the output of the command you wrote, use this syntax :

```
A=$( $top -bn1 | grep CPU |head -1 |sed s/"%"/""/g|awk '{print $8}' )
```

`A` and `B` are string variable. You can either convert then to integer using the syntax `A=$(($A))`. However I recommend you to change the if statement to take string as parameter.

**Warning** : this works only with integer. To compare **float**, you could use `bc` command.

```
res=$(echo "10.5>10.4" | bc) # res=1 in this case
res=$(echo "10.5<10.4" | bc) # res=0 in this case
```

Finally, **your script** is that :

```
A=$( $top -bn1 | grep CPU |head -1 |sed s/"%"/""/g|awk '{print $8}' )
B="2"
res=$( echo "$A>$B" |bc )
if [[ $res -eq 1 ]]
then
    # True
    echo "CPU usage to high, value is $A"
else
    # False
    echo "CPU usage OK, lower than $B"
```

Comment: This works but for the integer assumption; actual values here are floating-point.

Comment: Backticks have been deprecated for well over 20 years.  Use `$()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I didn't know that, I changed it in my post.